# Elastic Beanstalk Django Nginx Cache Images

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed an Elastic Beanstalk application and it is using nginx instead of Apache. I would really like to have browser image caching working but I can not find anything online about setting the caching headers with nginx. This was much easier with Apache. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this into two problems.

1. Extending AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform configurations for `nginx`
2. Configuring `nginx`

**1. Extending AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform configurations for `nginx`**

Within your application deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you can include an `.ebextensions` directory containing configuration files, including `nginx` related `.conf` files.

For your scenario, that could look like:

```
~/my-applicaiton/
|-- .ebextensions
|   `-- nginx
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- image_caching.conf
```

You'll want to `.zip` this along with your deployment bundle ensuring the `.ebextensions` directory is at the root of the `.zip`.

Resources:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

**2. Configuring `nginx`**

Once you've introduced the `.ebextensions` extension of the existing `nginx` configuration, you'll be focusing on how `nginx` can be configured to add the necessary Headers for browser caching to apply to assets.

This other answer may give you more insights on how to configure the location and expiry per asset for `nginx`.

https://serverfault.com/a/334871